# Break a loop when the user just input an enter in visual c++ or code blocks

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks

I want to know how to make stop a while loop when the user just input an Enter without asking to continue or , here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    bool flag = true;
    int userInput;

    while(flag){
        cout<<"Give an Integer: ";
        if(!(cin >> userInput) ){ flag = false; break;}
        foo(userInput);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: The problem is that when the user just input an empty line, my loop doesn't end, it still asking for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getline.  Break if the string is empty.  Then convert the string to an int.

```
for(std::string line;;)
{
    std::cout << "Give an Integer: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    if (line.empty())
        break;
    int userInput = std::stoi(line);
    foo(userInput);
}
```

`std::stoi` will throw an exception on failure, handle that however you want.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't know if there is a better way to do it. Anyway thanks for your answer, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userInput;
    string strInput;

    while(true){
        cout<<"Give an Integer: ";
        getline(cin, strInput);
        if (strInput.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        istringstream myStream(strInput);
        if (!(myStream>>userInput))
        {    
            continue; // conversion error
        }

        foo(userInput);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't work.  Using operator >> with a string, cin will just wait until you enter valid characters, ignoring any whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: Very true. Thx. I edited my answer with getline() (I took it from your answer).